# Play facebook video in android app

Tags: android, facebook, video-player

I want to play videos posted on facebook. I h've got the video id but dont know how to play them, One solution was to play in iframe but needs flash player. Is there any other way, please suggest.

Comment: Do you have the source path of the video?

Comment: while embedding i create path like this https://www.facebook.com/video/embed?video_id="+facebookID+"

But it needs flash player.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Try this.

```
VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.view);
MediaController controller = new MediaController(this);
videoView.setVideoPath("url of the video");
videoView.setMediaController(controller);
videoView.start();
```

This will play the video through the device media player.

You will need the permission listed below in your manifest file but you probably already have that.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" >
```

**update**

I don't know if this is really what you want without knowing more about your app but I've found this url to be more helpful because it handles all the flash issues but It takes the user into Facebook.

```
https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?v=10201503228394922
```

Comment: How can an embed url be open in video view?

Comment: WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_view);
    final WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
    settings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl("https://www.facebook.com/video/embed?video_id=10201503228394922");

Answer (score 0):

I had the very same issue and took days only to realise that using http:facebook..... ment that u have to run the web app and get the video embedded of which doees not make sense since what u require is the video itself so use the facebook developer graph and get the video link.

```
Uri url=Uri.parse("https://fbcdn-creative-a.akamaihd.net/hads-ak-xpt1/v/t43.1792-4/12306470_527989610700804_467115139_n.mp4?efg=eyJ2ZW5jb2RlX3RhZyI6InN2ZV9oZCJ9&oh=2f3e083591a1e02b795abb3b49352eb3&oe=5671564A&__gda__=1450326634_da5709bd94571df40f3ec161288e7bd5");
VideoView video = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView);
MediaController controller = new MediaController(this);
video.setVideoURI(url);
video.setMediaController(controller);
video.start();
```